# Uncaught Syntax Error using JavaScript server side variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with Node.Js on server side, it generates a JSON, that I convert in an Object, and I need to access it from client side, in particular from a script in a HTML page.

EDIT: Server-side code

On the server side this is the code when the post request happens:

```
exports.plot = function(req, res){
    var json;
    request.post({
            uri:"http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/datapoints/query",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body:req.body.txt1
            },function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                    var json = JSON.parse(body); //JSON converted in an object
                    res.render('query', json);

                }
            }
        );

};
```

It was suggested me to use server side scripting (like the one used in ASP.NET) to access that object.

So I've used that syntax to get the values I want, however on the Chrome console I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpeted token (" .

Where I'm wrong?

Here's the code

```
<script>
 function(){
    var start = new Date();
        var queryLength = <%= queries.length %>, // This gives me a number correctly
        timestamps = [],
        tagsString = [],
        values = [],
        dataPoints = [];

        var metric = <%= queries[0].results[0].name %>; //Gives me correctly a string

    //il for che mi scorre tutta la risposta    
    for (var j = 0; j < queryLength; j++)
    {

    }
} 
</script>
```

the complete error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( jquery-1.9.1.js:603
(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.1.js:603
jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery-1.9.1.js:604
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.9.1.js:6187
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery-1.9.1.js:5949
(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.1.js:6074
jQuery.extend.access jquery-1.9.1.js:852
jQuery.fn.extend.html jquery-1.9.1.js:6038
(anonymous function) format-timestamp.js:36
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
done jquery-1.9.1.js:8074
callback jquery-1.9.1.js:8598
```

Comment: What kind of templating engine are you using? If you are not using a templating engine, then the html that gets sent to the broweser contains `<%= queries.length %>` and it is not surprising that there is a syntax error in your JS.

Comment: I don't think you've included the part of your JavaScript code that generates the error. What are you doing in the `for` loop? Do you have more JavaScript code to show?

Comment: @AnalogWeapon, no, the error is on also without for loop

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg what do you mean by templating engine? I use only Node.js at server side, now inside Nodeclipse because it's in developement

Comment: Then how does `<%= queries.length %>` get translated into html?

Comment: Yes it becomes a value

Comment: I think Markviduka is an ASP.NET environment, so this HTML is getting pre-processed by ASP. Those `<%` / `%>` tags delimit ASP.NET code, correct?

Comment: @AnalogWeapon  I'm not in an ASP.NET env, i'm using Node.js at server side, in Eclipse Ide.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, then my latest answer is a little off. But I think the same principle might still be the problem. i.e. The value as it is output from node.js isn't getting serialized properly and it just ends up being a string on the client side. What do you see in the browser JavaScript console if you add the line `console.log(queryLength)` right after the line in which you assign it a value?

Comment: But if you're in a node.js environment, I'm not sure what the `<% %>` tags are supposed to do. I'm a little confused, honestly. I see why Andrew was asking about a templating engine now...

Comment: Well I see the exact value, in that case "1" (obviously without " ")

Comment: @AnalogWeapon I'm sorry about using your time (and the one of other users). I'm confused too, anyway i'm sure that those tags can be used in node.js. Altough it works for simple arrays. I have those problems with more complex objects

Comment: If you see the value `1` without any quotes around it, that's good (assuming you expect a simple integer). When you have the problem with the more complex objects, I suspect that is when you're running into the serialization issue. Try `console.log` on those values both on the client _and_ on the server (from node.js) to try to get a clue as to what exactly you're sending to the JavaScript that the client is running. (Don't worry about wasting my time. I wouldn't be on here if I didn't want to try and help people like they've helped me) :)

Comment: I've done several tests and how I said before, the problems (i don't know why) coming from complex objects, and not from calling length of something or maybe retrieving a one-dimension array. In addition, I use `<% %>` tags inside and I'm doing some manipolation here. I don't no why but there's no way to simply save into a variable a complex object :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a jquery error.. I think the `function(){}` call is wrong you need `$(function() {});` don't forget to add `);` at the end.

Or if it's not the Jquery ready function that your are calling you have an syntax error and should  do `function myFunction(){}`

try this

```
// replace `function(){}` width  `$(function() {});`
$(function() {
  var start = new Date();
        var queryLength = <%= queries.length %>, // This gives me a number correctly
        timestamps = [],
        tagsString = [],
        values = [],
        dataPoints = [];

        var metric = <%= queries[0].results[0].name %>; //Gives me correctly a string

    //il for che mi scorre tutta la risposta    
    for (var j = 0; j < queryLength; j++)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway I've tried that syntax without the `<%= %>` code and it works properly. I don't think is a jQuery problem, or to be more precise, it won't be a standard jQuery problem, maybe it's related with the server side scripting (I use also Node.js)

Answer (score 2):

That error has nothing to do with the JSON or the server side code.

The syntax error is here:

```
function(){
```

It looks like the beginning of a function expression, but you are not using it as an expression. It conflicts with the syntax of a function declaration, which would look something like this:

```
function functionName(){
```

The parser expects the name of the function to follow the `function` keyword, but instead there is a parenthesis.

If you want to declare a function, there should be a function name. If you want to use a function expression, then you need to use it as an expression, i.e.:

```
(function(){
  ...
})();
```

I added the `()` to actually call the function also, as it otherwise would just create the function and throw it away without calling it.

If you want to use the shorthand for the jQuery `ready` event, it looks like this:

```
$(function(){
  ...
});
```

#### Edit:

To recreate an object or an array in the Javascript code, you have to print it in the code in literal syntax. You can use JSON for this, as that is a subset of Javascript object syntax.

Pseudo code (I don't know what libraries node.js have for JSON):

```
var queries = <% toJson(queries) %>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway, as written in the other response, the problem should be related to the server side code, because once this is commented the error disappears. I tried also assigning a name to the function as you suggested, but nothing changes.

Comment: @Markviduka: The code that you posted gives that syntax error, but it's possible that you have a similar error somewhere else in the code if changing it doesn't fix it or at least gives a different error message. There is an error in the server code though, but that should not cause a syntax error; there are string delimiters missing around the string value: `var metric = "<%= queries[0].results[0].name %>";`

Comment: For instance, if I write `var query = <%= queries %>; alert ("Hello!");` the alert doesn't appear, if i comment variable query, it appears.

Comment: @Markviduka: As the variable `queries` is an array in the server code, you would not get the script representation of it when you print it, you would get the string representation of it. Convert it to a JSON string if you want to put in in the code.

Comment: As you written, with delimiters the metric variable gives no errors, and the alert works. So if it's possible with a string, why it couldn't be possible with an object? Indeed, if I write  `var object =  [<%= queries %>];` where `queries` is an object, the error returns.

Comment: @Markviduka: The string representation of a string is its string value, so by just putting it between delimiters it works as Javascript. The string representation of an object is not Javascript to create an identical object, so you can't just print it out in the code. If you look at the genrated code, it ends up as something like `var object = [(object Array)];`.

Comment: Also in that case gives the error, probably there's something related to server side scripting that I haven't understand

Comment: @Markviduka: In what case?

Comment: In the one when I use your syntax of var  `object `

Comment: @Markviduka: That's now code to try, that was an example of how if could look in the generated code.

Comment: @Markviduka: See my answer based off this comment thread. (It was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JavaScript in the browser isn't going to be able to understand the value of `query` as anything but a string. It doesn't matter if you output `[1,2,3]` or `{"foo":"bar"}`, the JavaScript is just going to interpret that as `var query = "[1,2,3]"` or `var query = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`.

As Guffa said in his comments: If you want to get the object in JavaScript you need to make sure ASP is outputting a valid JSON string representation of the object and then parse it in the JavaScript. So if your `query` object is `{foo: bar}` in ASP, you need to output the string `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"` from ASP. I don't know if ASP has any built in methods for this, but assuming it does (or you make one) and it's called `toJSONString()`: In your JavaScript, do:

```
var query = JSON.parse(<%= toJSONString(query) %>)
```

Comment: Not at all, and that's not what I said. It works fine to output an object in JSON format directly in the code, i.e. pseudo code: `<%= toJson(queries) %>`. There is no need to convert it to JSON and put the JSON in a string in the code, and the parse the JSON. JSON is a subset of Javascript object syntax, so it works fine to use it as Javascript code.